# Using UseInMemoryDictionary in Config.Net library

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, config, in-memory

I am new to using like in memory collections in .Net. So can anyone help me in how to use the Config.Net's UseInMemoryDictionary?

https://github.com/aloneguid/config?tab=readme-ov-file#inmemory

As far as I read the Config.Net, we should define an interface and build the configuration by specifying this Interface. But I have a doubt in how to define the values for the properties in the interface.

Should I derive a class using that interface and specify the values in the derived class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the same github repository, you can find the implementation of 'UseInMemoryDictionary' in https://github.com/aloneguid/config/blob/master/src/Config.Net/ConfigurationExtensions.cs. You can pass any Dictionary<string, string> at the time of initialization and it will convert it into IMySettings type instance with the help of Castle.Core proxies. If you don't pass a dictionary, it will create an empty store.